# Translação, rotação e escala de um retangulo

Tags: javascript, geometria, rotação

Imaginem os seguinte retângulo A e losango B:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O retângulo A tem as dimensões 4200 por 3000.
O losango B tem as dimensões máxima de 167 por 167, seus lados tem 98 por 98.

O retângulo A é equivalente ao losango B, por isso, gostaria de saber (uma formula genérica) como passar um ponto qualquer de A, ex: P(500, 400) para B.

Levando em consideração a translação, rotação e escala entre A e B. Se possível usando JavaSript na formula;

Para a escala estou usando uma regra de 3 simples.

Eu achei essa formula para a rotação:

```
function rotacionar(x, y, radianos) {
    var graus  = radianos * Math.PI / 180;
    var seno   = Math.sin(graus);
    var coseno = Math.cos(graus);

    x += 98;

    return {
        x: parseInt(x * coseno + y * seno),
        y: parseInt(y * coseno - x * seno)
    }
}
```

Só que não sei mais como juntar tudo e dar o ponto exato.

Obs.: É pra usar no Phaser.IO para que o usuário ande pelo mapa (A = pixels e B = locais onde ele pode andar)

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta nao faz parte do [escopo](/help/on-topic) do site.

Comment: Exato. Do jeito que a pergunta está, ela não faz parte do escopo porque é essencialmente um problema de matemática. Procure ao menos fornecer exemplo de código Javascript que vc já fez e tentou, que aí ela talvez entre mais facilmente no escopo do site.

Comment: Assim está melhor?

Comment: A tag correta adicional para sua pergunta seria computação gráfica.

Comment: Não achei essa TAG para adicionar

Answer (score 1):

Se eu me lembro bem dos livros de computação gráfica que li você tem que transladar o centro do retângulo para a origem (0,0) e tudo que estiver ligado a ele, rotacionar ao angulo desejado e transladar para o ponto antigo.

Se você aplicar a formula de rotação da forma como esta, o retângulo vai rotacionar em  volta da origem e não do seu centro como desejas.

Então para rotacionar algo deve-se transladar o eixo de rotação para a origem, rotacionar e voltar ao local.
A fórmula fica dessa forma:

xf = (xo - xr) * cos (@) - (yo - yr) * sin (@) + xr

yf = (yo - yr) * cos (@) + (xo - xr) * sin (@) + yr

Onde:

- (xo,yo) = Ponto que você deseja rotacionar
- (xr,yr) = Ponto em que você vai rotacionar o ponto acima (no seu
  caso o centro  do retangulo)
- (xf,yf) = O novo local do    ponto rotacionado
- @ = Angulo de rotação

[Este site tem o que precisa](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/CG/Aulas/Vis2d/Instanciamento/Instanciamento.htm)

Mas fica minha sugestão para não perder seu tempo programando na mão toda esta matemática porque poderás acabar por encontrar os Quaternions. Você poderia usar o excelente [Box2D](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net). Eu uso ele em C++ e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Como se chama isso na matemática? Se você lembrar posso correr atras de como fazer.

Comment: Ficamos negativos mas o que importa é o trabalho fluir. Valeu por ter me feito lembrar deste assunto.

Comment: Como vc usaria o Quaternions? nunca usei ele

Comment: Nem eu. Sempre usei alguma 3D/2D engine para evitar isto.

Comment: Cara, essa formula ai (mesmo eu achando q está certa) não deu o resulta q eu esperava, Ex.: se pegar no retangulo A o ponto (0,0) e tentar passar para um ponto do losango B, em nenhum momento tenho algo parecido como um ponto (98,0) ou (0,98), sabe pq?

Comment: A única falha e já corrigida é que ela não traz de volta ao ponto de origem. Então é só somar o ponto de rotação novamente ao resultado. Fiz um notebook explicando e mostrando isto:  https://github.com/kernill/Notebooks/blob/master/Rotação.ipynb